# encoding string

Tags: python, string, md5, encode

"afile" is a previously existing file.

```
handle=open("afile",'r+b')
data=handle.readline()
handle.close() 
#  signgenerator is a hashlib.md5() object

signgenerator.update(data)     
hex=signgenerator.hexdigest()
print(hex) # prints out 061e3f139c80d04f039b7753de5313ce
```

and write this to a file

```
 f=open("syncDB.txt",'a')
 #hex=hex.encode('utf-8')
 pickle.dump(hex,f)
 f.close()
```

But when i read back the file as

```
while True:
    data=f.readline()
    print(data)
```

This gives the output:

```
b'\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x00061e3f139c80d04f039b7753de5313ceq\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x00d9afd4bb6bc57679f6b10c0b9610d2e0q\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x008b70452c46285d825d3670d433151841q\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x00061e3f139c80d04f039b7753de5313ceq\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x00d9afd4bb6bc57679f6b10c0b9610d2e0q\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x008b70452c46285d825d3670d433151841q\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x00b857c3b319036d72cb85fe8a679531b0q\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x007532fb972cdb019630a2e5a1373fe1c5q\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x000126bb23767677d0a246d6be1d2e4d5cq\x00.'
```

How do i encode to get the same hexdigest back from these bytes??
Also I am getting some gibberish characters in syncDb.txt like "€X" after each line.How do I correctly write the data in a readable form??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unpickle the data:

```
pickle.load(open('syncDB.txt', 'r+b'))
```

What you have there is pickled data. Proof:

> >>> import pickle
>
> >>> pickle.loads(b'\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x00061e3f139c80d04f039b7753de5313ceq\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x00d9afd4bb6bc57679f6b10c0b9610d2e0q\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x008b70452c46285d825d3670d433151841q\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x00061e3f139c80d04f039b7753de5313ceq\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x00d9afd4bb6bc57679f6b10c0b9610d2e0q\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x008b70452c46285d825d3670d433151841q\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x00b857c3b319036d72cb85fe8a679531b0q\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x007532fb972cdb019630a2e5a1373fe1c5q\x00.\x80\x03X \x00\x00\x000126bb23767677d0a246d6be1d2e4d5cq\x00.')
> **'061e3f139c80d04f039b7753de5313ce'**

But there's no point in pickling a hex string. You can just put it in the file. The `pickle` module should be used with more complex structures, like arrays, dicts, or even classes.

Comment: Pretty sure you should always open a `pickle`d file in binary mode.

Answer (score 1):

Don't `pickle` the hexdigest, just write it out as text.

```
with open("afile",'rb') as handle:
    data=handle.readline()

signgenerator.update(data)
hex=signgenerator.hexdigest()

with open("syncDB.txt",'ab') as f:
    f.write(hex + '\n')

with open("syncDB.txt",'rb') as f:
    for data in f:
        print(data)
```

If you really want to use `pickle`, you need to use the [`pickle.load` function](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) to read the data back from the file.

Comment: f.write(hex + '\n')
                TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: You should specify if you're on Python 3 -- my code works on 2. You need to `hex.encode()` and use `b'\n'` to convert the unicode to bytes on Python 3.